# How to allow local scripts to run, with Auth enabled?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using SWFUpload and some other scripts that print and download PDF's.
The thing is that the machine tries to access a page in order to generate the data for the scripts, but it hits the Authorization requirements.
I am using a custom made ip check for this scripts and put them in $this->Auth->allow().

I would like to allow all requests from 127.0.0.1.
What is the correct workflow, for custom scripts?
Should I allow() all methods and checkIP() or should I make a user for the system and authorize him. I find the last one a little bit to much just for a local connection!

Comment: There are many ways of hiding the methods and put them in allow(), but I want a correct form using cake's Authorization.

Comment: Allow the url to access with out Auth.. then it will work

Comment: Which PDF component you are using ? Give the plugin name.. so that we can help you..

Comment: I am using my own FileComponent. I know that I can allow the url to be accessed without Auth, but I don't want to do that. As some scripts access sensible data and SWF uploads files on the server. I want all Auth restrictions to apply, but not for the 127.0.0.1. I am thinking about writing this check in the core, but is it safe enough? A simple IP check?

Comment: then  write a ip check..

Comment: I am doing this now, but the main problem is that the same methods are also used by users, this is why I need a system that works in both ways. I would like something to generally apply, because now I have to do this for every script/method and I have to manually check that the user has rights to be there. This is why I need to check if it's the machine and if not normal rules of Auth should apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out the solution, as it follows:

I wrote an ip check method in core class Security

```
public static function checkIPBased($userId = false, $ipPool = array()) {
        $permission = FALSE;

        //CHECK BY IP IN IP POOL
        $ipAllowed = array_merge($ipPool, array(
            'localhost',
            '127.0.0.1',
            '::1',
                ));

        foreach ($ipAllowed as $ip):
            if (strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ip) === 0)
                $permission = true;
        endforeach;

        //CHECK IF THE USER IS ACCESING HIS ORDER
        if ($userId && (($userId == AuthComponent::user('id')) || ((int) AuthComponent::user('group_id') === 1)))
            $permission = true;

        return $permission;
    }
```

After that I wrote in AppController in beforeFilter() the following code:

```
if (Security::checkIPBased())
            $this->Auth->allow();
```

This way I am allowing the machine to access all methods **while still using Auth Component**!